# How do I hide number of links in dired?

Tags: emacs, dired

99.9% of the time, I don't care how many links are pointing to a file. How do I get dired (or alternatively, ls) to not display the number of links?

For reference, the output of ls -l is something like:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root   dir 104 Dec 25 19:32 file
```

The number of links, in this case, is 1. ls has a flag to remove the group number (104) but not one to remove the number of links, from what I can tell.

I'm afraid editing the format will screw up dired's parsing, as ls has a special flag for producing output to dired.

Comment: To the "belongs-on-superuser" close vote: there's about a 95% probability that the answer to this involves writing elisp (emacs lisp) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control how things are displayed in dired, you can customize the variable `dired-listing-switches`.  However, as you noted, not displaying the number of links is not an option.

A slightly different approach would be to use the package [`dired-details`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredDetails), which hides all details until you want them.  This hides the number of links (but also hides other information).  Follow the link to find the package (and a [`dired-details+`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired-details%2b.el) which sounds like it fixes a couple minor inconveniences with `dired-details`).

Original answer information follows:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-l")
```

From the ["Entering Dired"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Enter.html) info page:

> The variable
>   `dired-listing-switches' specifies the
>   options to give to`ls' for listing
>   the directory; this string *must*
>   contain `-l'.  If you use a numeric
>   prefix argument with the`dired'
>   command, you can specify the `ls'
>   switches with the minibuffer before
>   you enter the directory specification.
>   No matter how they are specified, the`
>   ls' switches can include short
>   options (that is, single characters)
>   requiring no arguments, and long
>   options (starting with `--') whose
>   arguments are specified with`='.

Comment: I spoke too soon: the number I am referring to is the the number of links pointing to the file, not the inode. I think I got them confused because each inode stores the number of links. Sorry for the confusion; initial post updated accordingly.

Comment: (in response to your edit) dired-details looks exactly like what I'm looking for. Don't know how I missed it.

Comment: There's so much stuff out there.  Just yesterday I posted a link to a package that solved a problem, but Emacs already had built-in stuff that did nearly exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ls-lisp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/macs/manual/html_node/emacs/ls-in-Lisp.html) to customize the dired buffer display. `ls-lisp` is part of GNU Emacs (22.1 or perhaps even earlier)  `ls-lisp` has a `ls-lisp-verbosity` customize variable that will allow you to show/hide "links", "uid" and "gid". It also has other things that may tickle your customize fancy.

I like `ls-lisp` so much I use it everywhere, on my Windows and even Linux sessions.